# What is the difference between '|' and a ^ in CSS

Tags: html, css

The [attribute|=value] selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute starting with the specified value.

Comment: Use this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp to see the attribute selectors

Answer (score 1):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#selectors):

> `E[foo^="bar"]`   an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

> `E[foo|="en"]`    an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"